# Can I destructure items using interpolated strings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Context API to pass items from one component to another. I am destructuring items as one would do:

```
const { smallPrice, bigPrice } = useContext(Context)
```

I wondered if it would be possible to destructure them with interpolated strings, so that I can use the props.id from the component.

```
const { `smallPrice${props.id}`, `bigPrice${props.id}` } = useContext(Context)
```

This won't work however. Are there any alternatives to destructure things coming from context with interpolated strings?

Comment: You could use computed property names, but you'd have to declare static target variables anyway. No, don't do this.

Comment: Yeah, I'd recommend storing your `smallPrice` and `bigPrice` values in an array or object and access them that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). You reference the variable by a key and assign it to a known variable name. Example:

```js
const {
  [`smallPrice${props.id}`]: smallPrices,
  [`bigPrice${props.id}`]: bigPrices
} = useContext(Context);

console.log(smallPrices);
console.log(bigPrices);
```